# Comma in jsoncpp output string

Tags: c++, jsoncpp

I'm currently using jsoncpp 0.6 for my project. When I tried to serialize a real number (float) into a json file, I noticed that the output string contains a comma instead of a dot as a decimal mark. This causes serious problems when putting real numbers into a json array, because there the comma is used as a separator for the array entries.

You can reproduce it with:

```
Json::Value testVal(Json::realValue);
testVal = 1.2f;
std::string testString = testVal.toStyledString();
```

I get 1,200000047683716 instead of 1.200000047683716. Can anyone reproduce this? Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Which locale (language setting) is your system using?

Comment: This may be a bug, [link](http://sourceforge.net/p/jsoncpp/bugs/61/)

Comment: Thanks, that pushed me in the right direction. I got the expected output by adding `setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "C")` before my calls.

Comment: This locale problem is [fixed in 0.8.z and 1.y.z](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp/pull/3).